# How to access control inside parent control? (asp.net c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, parent

I have page with listview in it. There is label and dropdownlist in listview. I would like to access the text of label from ddlTags_Init() method.
Code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        DataKeyNames="id_Image" onitemdatabound="ListView1_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="TagsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Tags") %>' />
             <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTags" runat="server" OnInit="ddlTags_Init" >
             </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void ddlTags_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       DropDownList ddlTags = (DropDownList)sender;
       Label lblTag = (Label)ddlTags.Parent.FindControl("TagsLabel");
       string text=lblTag.Text;
}
```

At the moment i am stuck with

```
Label lblTag = (Label)ddlTags.Parent.FindControl("TagsLabel");
```

Anyone knows what am i missing? 
Thanks, Jim

Comment: Does this code not work or are you asking if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: No, i am not getting any results in string text, i cant get to the value of label.

Comment: Please click on the "edit" link button below your post and add information regarding the bug or what you are expecting that doesn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there are more than 1 elements in the listview datasource, why don't you put your code in the ItemDataBound handler? I think that it should work.

Comment: If im doing that, i have problems with data in dropdownlist (i have removed the code that follows after first 3 lines)

Comment: ok. do yoy find the exact problem? debugging, what you see in the Parent object?

Answer (score 0):

Init is too early to get the bind value of Label. In other words, label value hasn't been bind yet.

Instead you might want to consider using `ItemDataBound` method.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" 
     OnItemDataBound="ListView1_ItemDataBound" ...>
  ....
</asp:ListView>

protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        var ddlTags = e.Item.FindControl("ddlTags") as DropDownList;
        var tagsLabel = e.Item.FindControl("TagsLabel") as Label;
    }
}
```